# Javascript , looping through a form with select options, when value x is selected needs to show textarea on the right place

Tags: javascript, c#, forms

I'm looping through a table/form here, and I need some help with the javascript part. When the option "keuze" is selected it needs to show a textarea, but when I select it on an another row the textarea only appears on the first row. And I want it to appear below my selection field where I selected the option. I hope you guys can help me with this. (Sorry for my bad english :)

http://nl.tinypic.com/r/1glsup/8

My code :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckReason(val) {
        var element = document.getElementById('reasonDescription');
        if (val == 'keuze')
            element.style.display = 'block';
        else
            element.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>

<form>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="productsTable">
            <tr>Kies alstublieft het artikel dat u terug wilt sturen</tr>
            <tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    foreach (var product in item.products)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">@Html.CheckBox("products")</td>
                        <td valign="top"><img src="@product.image" /></td>
                        <td valign="top">
                        Beschrijving: @product.description
                        <br />
                        Naam: @product.name
                        <br />
                        Sku: @product.sku
                        <br />
                    </td>

                    <td valign="top"> Aantal</td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        Retourreden <br />
                        <select name="reason" onchange='CheckReason(this.value);'>
                            <option selected="selected">Geef uw retourreden op</option>
                            <option value="keuze">Verkeerde keuze</option>
                            <option value="defect">Artikel defect</option>
                        </select>
                        <div  id="reasonDescription" style='display:none;'>
                            <p >Omschrijving van de reden:</p> <br />
                            <textarea name="reasonDescriptionField" id="reasonDescriptionField"></textarea>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You missed a closing "</tr>". I count 3 <tr> and just 2 closing </tr>.

Comment: Ah I see thx, but that is not solving my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the id dynamically. Try this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckReason(val,descId) {
            var element = document.getElementById(descId);
            if (val == 'keuze')
                element.style.display = 'block';
            else
                element.style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>

    <form>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="productsTable">
                <tr>Kies alstublieft het artikel dat u terug wilt sturen</tr>
                <tr>
                    @{
                        int count = 0;
                        }
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        foreach (var product in item.products)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">@Html.CheckBox("products")</td>
                            <td valign="top"><img src="@product.image" /></td>
                            <td valign="top">
                            Beschrijving: @product.description
                            <br />
                            Naam: @product.name
                            <br />
                            Sku: @product.sku
                            <br />
                        </td>

                        <td valign="top"> Aantal</td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            Retourreden <br />
                            @{
                                count++;

                            <select name="reason" onchange='CheckReason(this.value,"reasonDescription_@count");'>
                                <option selected="selected">Geef uw retourreden op</option>
                                <option value="keuze">Verkeerde keuze</option>
                                <option value="defect">Artikel defect</option>
                            </select>
                            <div  id="reasonDescription_@count" style='display:none;'>                                    
                                <p >Omschrijving van de reden:</p> <br />
                                <textarea name="reasonDescriptionField" id="reasonDescriptionField"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            }

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `<div  id="reasonDescription" style='display:none;'>` is going to be created more than once, it will be created for each item in `item.products` so I would suggest finding another way instead of using the Id of the div.. use javascript Events and the `this` keyword.

As I mentioned above that's why your script is behaving that way, because the element you're pointing at is only the first `<div  id="reasonDescription" style='display:none;'>` created.